# LateInitializationError: Field 'currencies' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying this practice project but I am getting this lateIntialization field not initialized error I tried making them nullable but it still doesnot work. I tried initializing it in init state but it is still giving the same error but it still giving that late List currencies not intialized.

What can I try next?

Main.dart

```
...
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:untitled/services/api_client.dart';
    import 'package:untitled/widgets/drop_down.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    // ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Homepage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<Homepage> {
      ApiClient client = ApiClient();
      Color mainColor = const Color(0xFF212936);
      Color secondColor = const Color(0xFF2849E5);
    
      late List<String> currencies;
      late String from;
      late String to;
    
      late double rate;
      late String result = "";
    
      Future<List<String>> getCurrencyList() async {
        return await client.getCurrencies();
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        (() async {
          List<String> list = await client.getCurrencies();
          setState(() {
            currencies = list;
          });
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: mainColor,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 18.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
                  Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    child: const Text(
                      "Currency Converter",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 36,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          onSubmitted: (value) async {
                            rate = (await client.getRate(from, to))!;
                            setState(() {
                              result =
                                  (rate * double.parse(value)).toStringAsFixed(3);
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              labelText: "Input value to convert",
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: secondColor,
                              )),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                          children: [
                            customDropDown(currencies, from, (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                from = val;
                              });
                            }),
                            FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                String temp = from;
                                setState(() {
                                  from = to;
                                  to = temp;
                                });
                              },
                              // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                              child: const Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
                              elevation: 0.0,
                              backgroundColor: secondColor,
                            ),
                            customDropDown(currencies, to, (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                to = val;
                              });
                            }),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              const Text("Result",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 24.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                              Text(result,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: secondColor,
                                    fontSize: 36.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }


    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    class ApiClient {
      final Uri currncyURL = Uri.https(
        "api.fastforex.io",
        "/currencies",
        {"apiKey": "e64cd89c61-88ad358143-rcu0bj"},
      );
      Future<List<String>> getCurrencies() async {
        http.Response res = await http.get(currncyURL);
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
          var list = body["currencies"];
          List<String> currencies = (list.keys).toList();
          print(currencies);
          return currencies;
        } else {
          throw Exception("Failed to connect to API");
        }
      }
    
      Future<double>? getRate(String from, String to) async {
        final Uri rateUrl = Uri.https("api.fastforex.io", "/currencies", {
          "apiKey": "e64cd89c61-88ad358143-rcu0bj",
          "q": "${from}_${to}",
          "compact": "ultra"
        });
        http.Response res = await http.get(rateUrl);
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
          // ignore: unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps
          return body["${from}_${to}"];
        } else {
          throw Exception("Failed to connect to API");
        }
      }
    }
...
```

Comment: Try FutureBuilder instead of fetching list in initState! it must work, Happy codding!

Answer (score 0):

You are referring 'currencies' list before it is initialized. You have to wait until it's to be initialized with ApiClient response.
Simply write a condition in the UI to not to be built the relevant widget if the list is null.
(currencies list should be nullable for this approach since late fields cannot be used for null checks)

```
if(currencies!=null)...[
        customDropDown(currencies, to, (val) {
            setState(() {
              to = val;
            });
        }),
 ],
```

Comment: Which implies you make currencies not `late` but instead nullable. Which would be fine, you should just mention it, because it's not obvious from your answer.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for correction.